# JuliaPro can not start in Atom

Tags: julia, atom-editor

I just install Julia and then JuliaPro for the IDE. 
I can start Julia and work on it normally. However, when I open JuliaPro, I can not start Julia. I got this message after press Enter.

Do you know what happens and how to solve it ?

```
Press Enter to start Julia.
```

```html
fatal: error thrown and no exception handler available.
InitError(mod=:BinaryProvider, error=ErrorException("No download engines found. We looked for: power
shell, C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell, curl, wget, fetch, busybox. Install on
e and ensure it  is available on the path.
"))
rec_backtrace at /home/Administrator/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\stackwalk.c:94
record_backtrace at /home/Administrator/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\task.c:246
jl_throw at /home/Administrator/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\task.c:577
error at .\error.jl:33
macro expansion at .\logging.jl:318 [inlined]
#probe_platform_engines!#30 at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.1\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\Bina
ryProvider\src\PlatformEngines.jl:258
unknown function (ip: 0000000012498FCE)
jl_fptr_trampoline at /home/Administrator/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\gf.c:1831
jl_apply_generic at /home/Administrator/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\gf.c:2184 [inlined]
jl_apply at /home/Administrator/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\julia.h:1537 [inlined]
jl_invoke at /home/Administrator/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\gf.c:56
probe_platform_engines! at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.1\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\BinaryPr
ovider\src\PlatformEngines.jl:134 [inlined]
__init__ at C:\Users\julia\AppData\Local\Julia-1.0.1\share\julia\stdlib\v1.0\BinaryProvider\src\Bina
ryProvider.jl:28
jl_apply_generic at /home/Administrator/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\gf.c:2184
jl_apply at /home/Administrator/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\julia.h:1537 [inlined]
jl_module_run_initializer at /home/Administrator/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\toplevel.c:
90
_julia_init at /home/Administrator/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src/home/Administrator/buildb
ot/worker/package_win64/build/src\init.c:813
julia_init__threading at /home/Administrator/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/src\task.c:302
wmain at /home/Administrator/buildbot/worker/package_win64/build/ui\repl.c:227
__tmainCRTStartup at /usr/src/debug/mingw64-x86_64-runtime-5.0.3-1/crt\crtexe.c:329
mainCRTStartup at /usr/src/debug/mingw64-x86_64-runtime-5.0.3-1/crt\crtexe.c:212
BaseThreadInitThunk at C:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll (unknown line)
RtlUserThreadStart at C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll (unknown line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first time Atom installs at Julia `Atom.jl` at `Juno.jl` packages.

Start a Julia console (outside of Atom), go to package manager by pressing `]` and type:

```
(v1.0) pkg> add Juno
(v1.0) pkg> add Atom
```

Just in case check if they precompile:

```
julia> using Juno
julia> using Atom
```

Once installed, go to Atom options by pressing `Ctrl`+`,`. Now select `Packages` and for `julia-client` click settings - in the settings `Julia Path` enter the full path for your Julia executable (the same one that has `Juno` and `Atom` installed).

Now Julia has good chance to work.

If it does not try to delete the `.atom` folder (it can be found at `JuliaPro-1.0.1.1/.atom` or at `YOUR_HOME_DIRECTORY/.atom`). Sometimes Atom package updates cause Atom Juno to stop working properly and this is the only good option.

Let me know if that helped.

Comment: Thanks @Przemyslaw Szufel, this can also help i guess. 
What i did yesterday is reinstall Atom then open Atom, make a connection with Julia and download Juno from inside Atom. After that, i can open Atom when calling JuliaPro.

Comment: Whenever Atom crashes/stops working you do not need to reinstall - just delete the `~/.atom` folder - always helps. Beware that sometimes after updates Juno stops working. Again deleting the `~/.atom` and installing Juno plugin again is the best option I found so far.